# Decrease count of detached tags

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have `Post` and `Tag` models

For adding tag to post I have:

```
public function addTag($tag) // $tag is string
{
    $slug = Str::slug($tag);

    $t = Tag::where("url", $slug)->first();

    if(!$this->in_array_field($slug, 'name', $this->tags))
    {
        if(!isset($t))
        {
            $t = new Tag;
            $t->name = $tag;
            $t->url = $slug;
            $t->count = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            $t->increment('count');
        }

        $this->tags()->save($t);
    }

    return $t->id;
}
```

After adding all tags I invoke `sync` to remove tags which are not any more in set

```
$this->tags()->sync($tagsIds); // $this is Post model
```

Everything is working, but how to decrease detached tags `count`?

Is there any handler or shoud I merge arrays and compare if not in old set - `attach` and `increase`, not in new set - `detach` and `decrease` or completly another way.

Answer (score 0):

In my personal blog, I use sql to get the count (I have a relatively low number of tags so it has a low over-head + plus I cache the result):

```
// Get list of tags, ordered by popularity (number of times used)
return \DB::table('tags_articles')->select('name', 'url_name', 'tag_id', \DB::raw('count(`tag_id`) as `tag_count`'))
               ->join('tags', 'tags.id', '=', 'tags_articles.tag_id')
               ->groupBy('tag_id')
               ->orderBy('tag_count', 'DESC')
               ->take($limit)
               ->get();
```

**Alternatively**, you may want to run a separate query to update each tag count separate from that process - either in a cron, or as a new query run after `sync()` is called. Assuming you hav a low amount of writes (aren't often tagging items many times per second), either way *probably* won't cause too many bottlenecks.

**Lastly**, there are "events" fired after database updates. See if some of these [model events](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-events) can be used to update the count after an insert ('saved') to your Tag model.

Comment: Imho, none of this is elegant solution, but thx, maybe I will use something

Comment: What would be the ideal situation in your use case? Perhaps there's improvements to be made.

Comment: I already solved it by `foreach($this->tags as $tag) { if(!in_array($tag->name, $tags)) { $this->tags()->detach($tag->id); $tag->decrement('count'); } }` - if one of all tags is not in $tags (set from input), its detached and decremented